# Highcharts Pie chart longer text

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As the example image displays, I'm having problems with highcharts data labels in the situation where the text is longer. I also created an JSfiddle example. A solution would be to limit the length of string to i.E. max 20 strings and put "..." to the end of text, so a longer text would look like: "Another long text wit...". But I want to find out an different solution, so my question is: how to solve long text issue which occurs only on HC Pie chart?
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfnawems/1/)

```
[{
                name: "Microsoft Internet Explorer Looooooooooonggggggggggggg",
                y: 56.33
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `width: '100px'` into `plotOptions > pie > style`:

```
style: {
    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black',
    width: '100px'
}
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rfnawems/2/